# Parameterized test: selectively run for only one data point

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have a `Parameterized` test that is fed, say, with files:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class FileTest {
...
public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
     return IteratorUtils.toList( FileUtils.iterateFiles(testFilesDir
                                                        , TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE
                                                        , (IOFileFilter) null) );
 }
```

Whether it's files on a file system, rows from a table or URLs makes no difference, really. Just a `Parameterized` test that's fed with a large amount of data points and takes a **long** time to conclude.

Now I am running the test, say 10,000 files and I detect a problem with file #9,203. I fix the bug and to
verify the fix I want to re-run the test, but only for this particular file (because I can't wait 2 hours). Subsequent re-runs (after the fix is verified) should of course comprise the entire data set.

Is there any way to do that, e.g. by supplying some run-time parameters in a console-invocation of JUnit so that only one particular data point is used?

Comment: Are you running the tests from your IDE or from a build tool?

Comment: @StefanBirkner command line invocation of an Ant build.xml file that uses the `junit` task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so in the end I found a way to accomplish this. Use a constructor for your parameterized test class that also takes a friendly name that you can easily pass from the command line. E.g. something like:

```
private final File   testFile;
private final String friendlyTestName;

public FileTest(File testFile, String friendlyTestName) {
    this.testFile = testFile;
    this.friendlyTestName = friendlyTestName;
}
```

Of course, you would then have to generate the appropriate tuples in the method that provides the data points. E.g. in the example below the friendly name is simply the filename of the test file (without the path; let's assume that they are unique):

```
@Parameters(name= "{index}: {1}")
public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
    Collection<File> _rv = IteratorUtils.toList( FileUtils.iterateFiles(testFilesDir, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, (IOFileFilter) null) );
    Collection<Object[]> rv = new ArrayList<>();
    for (File f : _rv)
        rv.add(new Object[]{f, f.getName()});
    return rv;
}
```

Then, when invoking Ant from the command line pass a `target-friendly-name` parameter:

```
ant -Dtarget-friendly-name=a-005 test
```

... and make sure it is conveyed all the way to the `junit` Ant task. E.g. in your `build.xml` file you should have something like:

```
<junit printsummary="${junit.summary}" showoutput="${junit.output}">
    <sysproperty key="target-friendly-name" value="${target-friendly-name}"/>
    ...
</junit>
```

Finally, in the test method itself use `assumeTrue` to demand that the friendly name of the data point equals the target friendly name (if present; otherwise all tests are run).

```
@Test
public void testFile() {
    assumeTrue( (targetFriendlyName==null)||(targetFriendlyName.equals(friendlyTestName)) );
    ...
}
```

I was looking for a way to directly use the `{index}` property of the [Parameters](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) annotation which would have removed the need to define a separate `friendlyName` but haven't figured a way to do so; hence this solution requires the unnatural addition of a friendly name field in the test class.